# Is there a proper way to handle database connection in class?

Tags: php, database, class, interface

I usually store PDO object as a member. However, during practice dependency injection, I have a issue that I can't decide an elegant way of handling database connection.

!! What I've done.
  In every instantiating the class, I always pass PDO object to the constructor. Constructor stores a reference of given PDO object.

```
class Examples
{
    /* Properties */
    public $db;

    /* Constructor */
    public function __construct(PDO &pdo)
    {
        $this->db = $pdo;
    }

    //..
}
```

It works well, even that I'm suffering unknown reason. I'm haunted some bzar doubt, `Am I doing right?`

The main question is, how can I give database connection to certain class? extend PDO? pass PDO object as parameter? or Make another class extends PDO and implements both? ..??? ??? ???????????? ;OTL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass the $pdo as a reference using ampersand, because in PHP the objects are passed by references by default.
Your example is fine. 
Never extend your entity/model class with PDO, unless doing a specialised version of PDO.
If you have plenty of classes using $pdo and other services (such as sessions, file system, APIs etc.) then you can think about creating a service manager (container) and then calling it to get the reusable objects, such as your $pdo.
In case you will replace PDO with something else in the future, you don't need to rewrite all the classes that are pulling it as an argument.